# Sequence inequality does not guarantee limit inequality

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Suppose that the sequences {an} and {bn} converge to A and B, respectively, and
suppose that there exists n1 such that for all n ≥ n1, we have an < bn. Verify that it
is incorrect to conclude that A < B.

As I see it, I am trying to find an example of two sequences, one less than the other, but whose limit point inequalities are reversed?

Comment: You won’t be able to get $B<A$, but you can still get $A\not<B$; what’s the possibility that you missed?

Comment: Think of a monotonic decreasing sequence and a monotonic increasing sequence that both go to the same limit.

Comment: $b_n= 1/n$, $a_n=0$, $a_n<b_n$ but $a_n,b_n\to 0$

Comment: I was thinking a(n) of 1/n^2    and b(n) of 1/n; is that the same kind of idea?

Comment: @MathRaider: Yes, it is (for $n\ge 2$).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $a_n = 1 + 1/n$ and $b_n = 1$ for all $n$.  Then $a_n > b_n$ for all $n$ but $a_n \to 1, b_n \to 1$.

Comment: same notion as Brian Bruce and Jose, thank you. I always have a hard time thinking of a single natural number as a sequence